# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. But I don't have any subscriptions that I know of?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

This is built in gatsby, and I only have 1 useEffect hook, it looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== `undefined`) { // to comply with gatsby build
      setWidth(window.innerWidth);
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => setWidth(window.innerWidth));
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize",  () => setWidth(window.innerWidth))
      };
    }
  }, []);
```

The warning only appears after using a gatsby `<Link>` and navigating to a new page, and then resizing the page. It doesn't happen when I load up the development page and just resize the page.

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Your'e not removing your event listener, because you hve to give the **same** function, not just an equivalent one, to `removeEventListener`; see `***` comments:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== `undefined`) { // to comply with gatsby build
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        // *** Create and remember the handler
        const handler = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth));
        // *** Set it
        window.addEventListener("resize", handler;
        return () => {
            // *** Remove it
            window.removeEventListener("resize",  handler);
        };
    }
}, []);
```

Since your previous `removeEventListener` didn't remove your handler, the next resize after the component unmounted would cause this error to occur.

Comment: *(Realized there had to be a dupetarget for this, so found one and CW'd this answer.)*